# finding the skin tone percentage of a person from an image (not a web cam feed ) ignoring the background

Tags: image, opencv, detection

I need to find the percentage of skintone of a person in a given image.

I have been able to count all the pixels with skin colour so far but I am having trouble ignoring the background of the person so I can count the number of pixels for the percentage.

```
BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 bg;
bg.nmixtures =3;
bg.bShadowDetection=false;

bg.operator ()(img,fore);
bg.getBackgroundImage(back);
```

`img` is my image. I was trying to separate the back and fore mat objects, but with the above code snippet `back` and `fore` take the same value as the `img`. Nothing is happening.

Can you point me in the right direction as to what changes I have to make to get it right?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run some similar code found here:

http://mateuszstankiewicz.eu/?p=189

I had to change a couple of things, but it ended up working properly (back and fore are not the same as img when displayed:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Mat frame, back, fore;
    VideoCapture cap(0);
    BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 bg;

    vector<std::vector<Point> > contours;

    namedWindow("Frame");
    namedWindow("Background");
    namedWindow("Foreground");

    for(;;) {
        cap >> frame;
        bg.operator ()(frame, fore);
        bg.getBackgroundImage(back);
        erode(fore, fore, Mat());
        dilate(fore, fore, Mat());
        findContours(fore, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
        drawContours(frame, contours, -1, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2);
        imshow("Frame", frame);
        imshow("Background", back);
        imshow("Foreground", fore);
        if(waitKey(1) == 27) break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i think the code u mentioned only works well when the "foreground" object is in motion - it successfully separates it from the background ... i tried it again adding those additional lines... this time the background has the entire image and foreground has blank...

Comment: i dont knw how to do it for static images , instead of feed from the webcam !!